# Can't connect Adafruit Metro ESP32-S2 to computer

Tags: c++, arduino

I recently bought an Adafruit Metro ESP32-S2 so I could connect it to my LED strips (WS2812B) and control it through my phone. I'm trying to connect it but it won't work. Through the Arduino IDE, I added this

*https://adafruit.github.io/arduino-board-index/package_adafruit_index.json*

into "Additional Boards Manager URLs" and chose the Adafruit Metro option.

I've tried switching to a USB 2.0 port, but this didn't change anything.

When holding the DFU button-down, pressing the reset button, and then letting go of the DFU button creates a new port (COM5). What's happening here?

I can connect through this new port, but whenever I try uploading it leaves me on uploading for about 30 seconds and then sends this error

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xcb
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xcb
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xcb
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xcb
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xcb
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xcb
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xcb
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xcb
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xcb
avrdude: stk500_recv(): programmer is not responding
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0xcb
Problem uploading to board.  See http://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/Troubleshooting#upload for suggestions.
```

There also may be a problem with the code I'm running, I'm not sure.

```
#include "WiFi.h"

const char* ssid = "Network Name";
const char* password =  "Network Passwords";

void setup() {

  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi..");
  }

  Serial.println("Connected to the WiFi network");

}

void loop() {}
```

How can I connect the Metro ESP32-S2 to my computer?
Please remind me if I'm missing any information needed.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more, I can only suggest this. Make sure you have selected the appropriate board and programmer in the ide, then make sure you have selected the right baudrate. Also be sure you didn't need to download an additional driver. since a com port shows up, It probably isn't a driver issue, but doesn't hurt to double check.

Its been a few years since I used anything arduino related, so I apologize for not being able to be too specific.

From what I remember, the code looks fine for testing a connection, I'd look more into the programing settings required for that board as it seems like a communication error between the board and programmer.